# App update deletes all cache and shared preferences

Tags: android

What can cause the app to delete all its settings and cache on update to a new version? It started to happen after migrating to Android Studio 3, however there were no any big changes in the project.

Also important - app deletes its settings on update only on release builds, everything is fine on debug builds. So it's very likely there is something with proguard.

Comment: Check if your database version is upgraded in new update and make sure you have not deleted any thing there

Comment: I don't have database, only files and shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the copy protection settings on playstore dashboard since the last release of your app ? If yes, it might delete the app's sharedpreferences. check that !

Comment: My problems also happens when I update the app manually with apk and without play store.